# Adding selected Items to collection

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write selected values in a listbox inside a collection.

I get an error in this line - `SelectedEnt.Add ItemReq, Key`

Here is my complete code,

```
Sub YesFormDataSubmit()
    Dim SelectedEnt As Collection
    Dim Key As Variant

    Set SelectedEnt = New Collection
    Key = 0

    For lItem = 0 To Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.ListCount - 1
        If Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            ItemReq = Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.List(lItem)
            If ItemReq <> "" Then
                Key= Key + 1
                SelectedEnt.Add ItemReq, Key
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: what error? why is `key` a variant type?

Comment: @DavidZemens Type Mismatch error. I tried to have Key as a Collection, but still got the same error. I am a beginner and learning VBA Collections. I am trying to use Variants as I want to call them back by Indexes.

Comment: I think the Key has to be a string value for a collection. You're passing an implicit numeric type, `key as Variant` has been assigned integer value.

Comment: @DavidZemens oh, Let me try that ! Thanks :)

Comment: You can call them by index without using the `key` at all. Just do `SelectedEnt.Add ItemReq`.  The items will be added to the collection in order, and will be accessible by index e.g., `SelectedEnt.Item(1)`, etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens Exactly what I was looking for, Write it as an answer. I will mark it :)

Comment: @DaveZemens You are correct.  The solution is to cast the Key to string CStr(Key).

Comment: It may be that `key` is not even needed in this case! I've added an answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` is not the index of a collection, consider:

```
Dim c as New Collection, i as Long
c.Add "David", "999"
c.Add "George", "14"

For i = 1 to c.Count
    Debug.Print c(i)
Next
```

The `key` must also be a string type, which is why you're getting a mismatch error, passing a long/integer instead of a string.

Unless you are using that key value for something else, you can omit it entirely.You can call them by index without using the `key` at all.

Just do `SelectedEnt.Add ItemReq`.

The items will be added to the collection in order, and will be accessible by index e.g., `SelectedEnt.Item(1)`, etc.

If you *do* need `key` for some other reason, then you must explicitly cast it to string:

`SelectedEnt.Add ItemReq, CStr(Key)`

Answer (score 1):

Your error because of that Key must be String.

```
Sub YesFormDataSubmit()
    Dim SelectedEnt As Collection
    Dim Key As Variant

    Set SelectedEnt = New Collection
    Key = 0

    For lItem = 0 To Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.ListCount - 1
        If Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.Selected(lItem) = True Then
            ItemReq = Sheets("Main").Ent_ListBox.list(lItem)
            If ItemReq <> "" Then
                Key = Key + 1
               'key must be string
                SelectedEnt.Add ItemReq, CStr(Key)
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```